# nvd3 tooltip position based on mouse pointer by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nvd3.js

I am trying to make a horizontal waterfall chart using nvd3 chart by customizing discretebar chart. It actually position the next bar based on the previous bar. d3 still thinks the bar is in the desired location and hence tooltip is shown there (not in the current position of the bar).

[demo](http://khan4019.github.io/horiz-waterfall-nvd3/horizWaterfall.html)

I have two problem

1. I want to place the tooltip on the current location of the bar.
2. I want to force y axis to start certain point. For example, [in the demo](http://khan4019.github.io/horiz-waterfall-nvd3/horizWaterfall.html), my Y axis starting point will be 4000 and -ve points (below 0) will not be displayed. I tried to pass forceY, it gets to the library but doesnt do anything. some implementation is not getting called in 14k lines of code

Thanks for trying to help me

Answer (score 0):

You can call (and personalize) the tooltip by calling the tooltip function, something like this:

```
chart.tooltip(function (key, x, y, e, graph) {
       return '<p><strong>' + key + '</strong></p>' +
       '<p>' + y + ' in the month ' + x + '</p>';
});
```

In your example, you can insert it just before the return chart; line.